# Get coordinates from each touch in UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` set up with `numberOfTouchesReguired = 2`. How can I get continuous coordinates of each finger on the view?

Currently I have this, but it seems to combine the location of all the touches into 1 coordinate.

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGPoint locationInView = [sender locationInView:nil];
}
```

Comment: @Till A long press will send continuous events as the fingers move.

Comment: @rmaddy my bad, you are right. Additionally, the allowed movement distance is configurable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the docs for `UIGestureRecognizer`. It provides the methods for this:

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        NSUInteger *touchCount = [sender numberOfTouches];
        for (NSUInteger t = 0; t < touchCount; t++) {
            CGPoint point = [sender locationOfTouch:t inView:sender.view];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, just found this too.